# Append audio in every exercise to div using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, audio

how are you doing?

I am trying to build a quiz app, and i can't discover how I append the audio of a specific question to the screen.

Basically, the user sees a question, three answers, and an audio.

How would I point each audio to the current exercise?

It is recognizing the first audio, but when I jump to the second question, it shows two audio players aligned and then they disappear.

The HTML file:

```
 <div id="navContent">

  <div id="game1"></div>
  <div id="game2"></div>
  <div id="audioContainer"></div>
  <div id="audioContainer2"></div>

 </div>
```

The JS

```
            $(document).ready(function () {

            var questionNumber=0;
            var audioNumber=0;
            var questionBank=new Array();
            var stage="#game1";
            var stage2=new Object;
            var evento = "#audioContainer";
            var evento2 = new Object;
            var questionLock=false;
            var numberOfQuestions;
            var score=0;


            $.getJSON('../../core/part1.json', function(data){

              numberOfQuestions = data.primeiro.length;

                  for(i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++){
                    questionBank[i] = [];
                    questionBank[i].push(data.primeiro[i].question);
                    questionBank[i].push(data.primeiro[i].option1);
                    questionBank[i].push(data.primeiro[i].option2);
                    questionBank[i].push(data.primeiro[i].option3);
                    questionBank[i].push(data.primeiro[i].audio);
            }

            displayQuestion();

            });


            function displayQuestion(){


             var q1;
             var q2;
             var q3;
             var audioFile = questionBank[questionNumber][4];
             var rnd=Math.random()*3;
            rnd=Math.ceil(rnd);

             var wordsShow = $('<li class= "center_txt"><div id="1" class="word-pt bluedark_txt">'+q5+'</div><div id="2" class="bluish_txt word-EN">'+q4+'</div></li>')
             var audioShow = $('<audio controls id="audioPlayer"><source src='+audioFile+' type="audio/mp3"></audio>');



            if(rnd==1){q1=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q2=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q3=questionBank[questionNumber][3];}
            if(rnd==2){q2=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q3=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q1=questionBank[questionNumber][3];}
            if(rnd==3){q3=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q1=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q2=questionBank[questionNumber][3];}

            $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">'+questionBank[questionNumber][0]+'</div><div id="1" class="option">'+q1+'</div><div id="2" class="option">'+q2+'</div><div id="3" class="option">'+q3+'</div>');

  //here is where I try to append the audio, not working
            $("#audioContainer").append(audioShow);

             $('.option').click(function(){
              if(questionLock==false){questionLock=true;    



              //correct answer

              if(this.id==rnd){
              // $("#feedbackBox").append('<div class="feedback1">CORRECT</div>');


               score++;


               }
              //wrong answer    
              if(this.id!=rnd){
              // $("#feedbackBox").append('<div class="feedback2">WRONG</div>');

              }

              setTimeout(function(){changeQuestion()},1000);
             }})

            }//display question


                function changeQuestion(){

                    questionNumber++;
                    wordNumber++;
                    audioNumber++;

                if(stage=="#game1"){stage2="#game1";stage="#game2";}
                    else{stage2="#game2";stage="#game1";}

                if(evento=="#audioContainer"){evento2="#audioContainer";evento="#audioContainer2";}
                    else{evento2="#audioContainer2";evento="#audioContainer";}

                if(questionNumber<numberOfQuestions){displayQuestion();}else{displayFinalSlide();}

                 $(stage2).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"slow", function() {$(stage2).css('right','-800px');$(stage2).empty();});
                 $(stage).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"slow", function() {questionLock=false;});

                $(evento2).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"slow", function() {

                    $(evento2).css('right','-800px');

                    $(evento2).empty();});

                 $(evento).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"slow", function() {questionLock=false;});

                }//change question
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: you can try to insert ``audio`` tag inside each ``div``

Comment: Hey @DonaldWu thanks for answering man! I am already doing it, look **var audioShow = $('<audio controls id="audioPlayer"><source src='+audioFile+' type="audio/mp3"></audio>');** and **$("#audioContainer").append(audioShow);**